# what does './' before a python filename do?

Tags: python, unix, flask

I'm following a Flask tutorial, in which I created a virtual environment to run the application.

To run the file, it asks me to run this command:

`./run.py`

as opposed to:

`python run.py`

What does the `./` do exactly and why is it necessary?

Comment: This is not a question about Python, but about the Unix shell.

Comment: `./` just tells the shell to look in the current directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used because the current directory is not in `$PATH`. And the reason why it is not in the current directory on that list is security.

So in simple terms you can say that the `./` says 'search in the current directory for my script rather than searching at all the directories specified in `$PATH'`.